# Cordova minifier doesn't minify the browser platform

Tags: javascript, android, ios, css, cordova

I downloaded the `cordova-minify` plugin which minifies my Cordova app javascript code. I tried running the command:

> cordova build browser

I get

> cordova-minify STARTING - minifying your js, css, html, and images.
>   Sit back and relax!
>
> Hook currently supports only Android and iOS

Why the minifier can't minify the browser version? What it means "Hook currently supports only Android and iOS"? What's `Hook`? The javascript code is exactly the same as the android platform and it works perfectly on that one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.
The message you are seeing is written at [line 107](https://github.com/alastairparagas/cordova-minify/blob/bac3d0c53da9b2a18fd932b61201c13dbe6ebafb/after_prepare/cordova-minify.js#L107)

It is due switch case starting from 99

```
switch (platform) {
case 'android':
    platformPath = path.join(platformPath, platform, "assets", "www");
    break;
case 'ios':
    platformPath = path.join(platformPath, platform, "www");
    break;
default:
    console.log('Hook currently supports only Android and iOS');
    return;
}
```

if you know the path for browser platform. you can add another case for browser platform after that it should work.

Here are the steps you can follow to make the changes

1. fork [repo](https://github.com/alastairparagas/cordova-minify)
2. clone. make changes. commit it.
3. Use this new module into your cordova project

Consider making an pull request to original so that others can solve their problem

Comment: ok thank! do you see any reason why they didn't add the browser minification? seems trivial to add the correct "case" in the switch statement

Comment: Developer might not be aware about browser platform in cordova.